# can we have a WizardPage inside a WizardPage in SWT?

Tags: java, swt

can we make a WizardPage inside a WizardPage ? That will include two next, back buttons. One set of next, back and finish button will be of outer WizardPage (main) and another set of next , back and finish will be of inside WizardPage.
please let me know if this is possible . Thank you in advance .

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this easily. A wizard requires to be within a class which implements `IWizardContainer` (or more usually `IWizardContainer2`). The only standard class that implements this is `WizardDialog` which can't be used for this. So you would have to implement some new wizard container class to make this work.

I would also think this could be very confusing to the user.